# Solr + Spring Roo separate index for each customer

Tags: java, solr, spring-roo

We're trying to add search functionality to our application. The search will be over customer data in a multi-tenant application. We need to be careful to make search people can't see or search for other people's data.

Spring Roo allows you to have an entity be searchable. Is there a way to limit the scope of the results to a particular customer id/name?

The project lead asked specifically if there was a way to divide it so each customer had their own index (segment?) in Solr. Has anyone tried this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're not giving users unfettered access to the solr interface, I would think that a simple [`fq` (filter query)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) would work. You would do something like `&fq=customerid:1234`.

Alternatively, if you need *actual* separation between the indexes, you can use [solr cores](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin), but these have to be configured independently.

Comment: Noob question: Can you combine filterqueries with "fuzzy queries"?

Comment: Sure. `fq` limits the result set, then you do the fuzzy query in the main query: `q=foo~0.8&fq=customerid:1234`